# Type of singularity at $z=\infty$ in $\frac{1+e^z}{1-e^z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

In my book, the poles of $f(z)$ have been found out as $z=(2n+1)πi$. So, the singularity is non-isolated essential as $z=\infty$ is a limit point of these poles. I understand this.

However, if I compute the limit of $f(z)$ as $z\rightarrow∞$ I get,
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-z} - 1}{e^{-z} + 1} = -1$$

This must mean that there is a removable singularity at $z=\infty$. How am I wrong here?

Comment: $e^{-z}$ does not tend to $0$ as $z \to \infty$.

Comment: What happens to $e^{in\pi}$, for example?

Comment: Oh I get it. So, the limit does not exist.